# How to recover deleled files on server using Total Commander?

Tags: linux, ftp, total-commander, file-recovery

I used Total Commander and connected FTP to write website. Today I accidently deleted some files. How to recover them?

Recover using Total Commander or log in Putty? If using Putty, what commands are used to recover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far as I can tell, [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) does not have file-versioning, backup or trash-can support features.

If your PC contains originals/copies of the files, use Total Commander to re-upload them to the website.

If not, ask the web-server administrator to restore the files from backup.

If you don't have backups, re-create the files.

If the files cannot be recreated and are very valuable, have the server turned off *immediately* and shipped to a data recovery specialist.

Comment: Can't we recover them from linux trash can? I hope it's possible.

Comment: Linux doesn't have a system-wide trash can. Desktops like Gnome and KDE may have a trashcan that is used by their GUI file-manager applications (nautilus etc). The FTPD daemon (i.e service) won't use a Trashcan, when you tel the FTPD to delete a file, it deletes it. It doesn't look for trashcans.